# Phonegap app playing mp3 using Media plugin does not work

Tags: android, cordova, audio, media

I've developed file reader in phonegap with following path:

var defaultPath = 'file:///storage/sdcard0/';

So i'm able to list all file on sdcard and select one folder with audio files to load. So my list of audio files looks like:

```
i[1] = 'file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/audio/file.mp3';
i[2] = 'file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/audio/file1.mp3';
```

Then I try to init song using Media plugin ( installed ) with following piece of code:

```
var media = new Media(i[1]);
media.play();
```

But audio does not play or do nothing. But when I'm trying to test it using PhoneGap APP all works fine this just isn't work when I make build and try to test app from build.

Comment: I jus dint understand last part of your post. You say its working fine as phonegap app and dont work on build. How can you test app without build?

Comment: You can have PhoneGap APP in PC + Mobile so you're able to connect and see APP faster instead of making build all the time. So in that case it was working using PhoneGap APP but after i've made build using cordova build android and install app from .apk playing songs stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue by myself. 
Android does not let read files on local storage or on sdcard via path starting from root `/storage/sdcard0` `/storage/sdcard1`. So when we would like to access local storage or sdcard we must access it via `file:///mnt/sdcard/` for sdcard and `file:///mnt/storage/sdcard1/` for phone storage.

Small example how to read entries from sdcard or phone storage:

```
var path = 'file:///mnt/storage/sdcard1/'; 
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, function(entry){
    var reader = entry.createReader();
    reader.readEntries(showEntries);
});

function showEntries(entries){
   var entries = [];
   for(var i =0; i < entries.length; i++){
       var entry = entries[i];
       var data = {
           name: entry.name,
           path: entry.fullPath,
       };

       entries[i] = data;
   }

   console.log(JSON.stringify(entries));
}
```

Hope that this will help with same issue as I had because this is not documented in phonegap.

Comment: I doubt your first statement as i have tried out creating folder in sdcard and also was able to access the files in the folder by accessing it from the sdcard root using cordova.file.externalRootDirectory

Comment: Did you tried that with apk build ? Try to make build and load data and play it from that path. Testing in phonegap enviroment had work for me bot not when I install app in mobile device.

Comment: I tried out accessing the file stored in external root directory(sd card in android) and i was able to successfully access it and open the same. I tried it both Android and iOS device. Not tried out playing sounds though

Comment: Then try to play sounds and I think it will not working. Issue is not in listing files but working and reading files. So issue will come when you start to access or use file in player for example the file will not play.