# mp3 embedded not working in Phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, audio, phonegap-build

I created a Phonegap application that uses an AUDIO element. It works perfectly on the browser.

If I install it as an app, the audio does not play anymore.

Using the Chrome DevTools I was debugging the app. I inspected the audio element and its source is something like `file:///android_asset/www/path/to/my.mp3`. If I changed to `http://whatever.com/path/to/an.mp3` it works.

If I change it to `file:///android_asset/www/path/to/unexisting.mp3` I got the error in the console:

> GET file:///android_asset/www/path/to/unexisting.mp3
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to
>   load because no supported source was found.

With `file:///android_asset/www/path/to/my.mp3` I wasn't getting any error in the console, simply I couldn't hear any sound.

In my `config.xml` I have

```
...
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
...
<feature name="Media">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler" />
</feature>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
...
```

and I did run `phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.media`.

I'm not using the `Media` class, but rather something like

```
<audio id="a" src="..."/>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('a').play()">Play</button>
```

I disconnected the phone from my laptop, but it still doesn't work.

I'm using phonegap 6.0.1.

What am I missing?

Later update:

I checked the Network tab from Chrome DevTools and I can see this

- Request

  - URL:file:///android_asset/www/path/to/my.mp3
  - Request Method:GET
  - Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
- Response Headers

  - Client-Via:shouldInterceptRequest
  - Content-Length:2
  - Content-Type:audio/mpeg
- Request Headers Provisional headers are shown

  - Range:bytes=0-1
  - User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 ...

Comment: i know its too late.. Did you find answer? you can check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101050/phonegap-app-playing-mp3-using-media-plugin-does-not-work

Comment: That's not the same. The files referred in that question/answer are stored in the phone storage or sdcard. Mine are embedded in the application.

Comment: But I found an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
<audio src="/path/to/my.mp3"/>
```

I used

```
<audio src="/android_asset/www/path/to/my.mp3"/>
```

and it worked.